# Running Elasticsearch-7.0 on a Travis Xenial build host

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04, travis-ci

The Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) image on [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org) comes with Elasticsearch-5.5 preinstalled. What should I put in my `.travis.yml` to run my builds against Elasticsearch-7.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add these commands to your `before_install` step:

```
- curl -s -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.0.1-amd64.deb
- sudo dpkg -i --force-confnew elasticsearch-7.0.1-amd64.deb
- sudo sed -i.old 's/-Xms1g/-Xms128m/' /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
- sudo sed -i.old 's/-Xmx1g/-Xmx128m/' /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
- echo -e '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC\n-Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true\n-Dlog4j.skipJansi=true\n-server\n' | sudo tee -a /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
- sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /etc/default/elasticsearch
- sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

The changes to `jvm.options` are done in an attempt to emulate the existing config for Elasticsearch-5.5, which I assume the Travis peeps have actually thought about.

According to the [Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#elasticsearch), you should also add this line to your `before_script` step:

```
- sleep 10
```

This is to ensure Elasticsearch is up and running, but I haven't checked if it's actually necessary.

Comment: Is this intentional to have line 3 and 4 duplicate?

Comment: They're not duplicates.

Comment: Yeah nvm found the little detail that is different. Got it to work even without these 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me.
BTW, the `sleep 10` is just in case you start your tests before elastic is ready so just to play safe give some time to start the server.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Also remove the entry for `elasticsearch` under services, like @musicalmindz mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

One small addition to @kthy answer that had me stumbling for a bit. You need to remove `- elasticsearch` from your services: definition in the .travis.yml otherwise no matter what you put in `before_install`, the default service will override it!

```
services:
  - elasticsearch
```

Remove ^^ and then you can proceed with the steps he outlined and it should all work smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to wait for the elastic search to start (which may be longer or shorter than 10 seconds) replace the `sleep 10` with this:

```sh
  host="localhost:9200"
  response=""
  attempt=0

  until [ "$response" = "200" ]; do
      if [ $attempt -ge 25 ]; then
        echo "FAILED. Elasticsearch not responding after $attempt tries."
        exit 1
      fi
      echo "Contacting Elasticsearch on ${host}. Try number ${attempt}"
      response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null "$host")

      sleep 1
      attempt=$[$attempt+1]
  done
```